# setting steps for input type=number

Tags: javascript, html

The following html tag displays a input field that accepts a number and also provides up, down arrows to increment, decrement the field values.
My required input field is an input with the value of the cricket over, so for example, after 1.5 if I click up arrow it should get converted to 2 or 2.0 and not 1.6

```
<input type="number" name="overs" step="0.1">
```

I know it requires some javascript to be executed when clicking the up and down arrow but I don't know how to do it. Can anyone suggest how to handle this arrow click event. Also the field accepts manually entered numeric value, again a validation is required to restrict the invalid values for cricket overs eg: 1.8 which is invalid.
Please guide.

Comment: why don't you set it to step="0.5"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an *event listener* (`input`) and **increment the integer value** is fraction value is getting **bigger than or equal to `0.6`**

```
input.addEventListener( "input", function(){
   var value = this.value;
   if ( value - parseInt( value ) >= 0.6 )
   {
      this.value = Math.ceil( value );
   }
})
```

**Demo**

```js
var input = document.querySelector( "[name='overs']" );

input.addEventListener( "input", function(){
   var value = this.value;
   if ( value - parseInt( value ) >= 0.6 )
   {
      this.value = Math.ceil( value );
   }
})
```

```html
<input type="number" name="overs" step="0.1">
```

For reducing the overs, listen to `keyup` as well

**Note**

- Below demo works with down-arrow key, not arrow click.

**Demo**

```js
var input = document.querySelector( "[name='overs']" );

input.addEventListener( "input", function(){
   var value = this.value;
   if ( value - parseInt( value ) >= 0.6 )
   {
      this.value = Math.ceil( value );
   }
});

input.addEventListener( "keyup", function(){
    var value = this.value;
    var step = +this.getAttribute( "step" );
    console.log(event.which);
   if ( event.which == 40 )
   {
      event.preventDefault();
      value = value - step;
      if ( (value - parseInt( value )) >= 0.5 )
      {
         this.value = parseInt( value ) + 0.5;
      }
   }
});
```

```html
<input type="number" name="overs" step="0.1">
```

Comment: It won't let me go back from integer number. Let's say if i reached at 2 and then press down key then it won't decrement the value by 0.1

Comment: I know, I only had implemented the increment of overs

Comment: It was a great input, @gurvinder and Harsh. For the first over it was going uptil 0.6 and then was changing to 1.0, its fine I made the necessary changes. Can you guide even for the decrement part.

Comment: Is there a way to identify whether up arrow is clicked or down arrow is clicked for adding separate listeners for each?

Comment: Let me check, I am not sure if it is possible.

Comment: @VrajeshDoshi You will need to save the old value as an attribute to compare if the value has got increased or decreased via arrow clicks.

Comment: OK. Thanks for the valuable inputs

Answer (score 0):

You could check if the fraction is > 0.5 and round it:

```js
document.querySelector('.input-round-up').addEventListener('input', function (e) {
  var value = e.target.value;
  var isDecrementing = value < this.__lastValue;
  if ((value % 1) > 0.5 && !isDecrementing) {
    e.target.value = Math.round(value);
  }
  this.__lastValue = value;
});
```

```html
<input class="input-round-up" type="number" name="overs" step="0.1" />
```

Comment: Increment and decrement is not stopping at 0.5 in the demo code

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, I thought you wanted it to do 1.6 -> 2, 2.6 -> 3 etc

Comment: No Worries, The code posted by Gurvinder is a grt one but working only for increment and not for decrement, would be glad if you could refer it and guide me for proceeding for decrement

Comment: Ok I don't really get what you mean as it works the same as his except correctly goes to the number after .5 rather than .6. Anyway, updated for decrement

Answer (score -1):

Try this link code

https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_input_number

```
 <input type="number" name="quantity" min="1" max="5">
```

Comment: While this sets minimum and maximum values, but doesn't affect the step values, which is what the question is about, and the OP seems to have managed to work out themself.